# Spark query in R

Tags: azure-databricks, sparkr

I'm translating a spark query from Python to R in databricks.What is the equivalent of below code in R.

```
categories= spark.sql("select name,place from table where XYZ ")
```

I tried to replicate the above code as following
categories <- sql(select name,place from table where XYZ)

but getting syntax error.

Comment: Could you please post here the code you use in R (including libraries) and the error it produces?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're just missing quotes around the query

```
categories <- sql("select name,place from table where XYZ")
```

Comment: So I was having problem with execution because in R sql queries can;'t be run directly.
Have to load data in a dataframe and create temp view and then access through query
df1 <- read.df("pass the path here",source="delta")
createOrReplaceTempView(df1, "Etemp)
result <- sql("SELECT name , place FROM temp")

Answer (score 0):

Have to load data in a dataframe and create temp view and then access through the query.

```
df1 <- read.df("pass the path here",source="delta") 
createOrReplaceTempView(df1, "temp") 
result <- sql("SELECT name , place FROM temp")
```